# ASP.NET MVC 4 2-factor authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, multi-factor-authentication

I'm working with legacy MVC 4 app and I'd like to add 2fa to it. App uses WIF and old Thinktecture Identity server for authentication.

Do I have to implement 2fa manually from scratch?

Is it supported starting from 5th version of ASP.NET MVC where ASP.NET Identity appears?

Does the update of Identity Server(it's planned to be updated to the last 4th version) will bring some functionality for it?

Please correct me if I'm making wrong statements in my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing out of the box in the core Identity Server 4 library that adds two factor authentication into the regular login flow. The login flow is still up to you to implement. Having said that, you can find an example on how to set up two factor authentication [here](https://damienbod.com/2017/07/14/implementing-two-factor-authentication-with-identityserver4-and-twilio/).